# Event Sourcing & Redis

Tags: c#, event-sourcing, redis

I'm using `StackExchange.Redis` library, it seems perfect.

Hard-coded events related BankAccount with ID 1:

```
// UNSORTED COLLECTION
public static List<Event> DomainEvents = new List<Event>()
    {
        new Event() { Data = @"{ 'Operation': 'WithdrawalPerformed', 'Amount': '10', 'UtcDateTime': '05/18/2019 18:47:41.084' }" },
        new Event() { Data = @"{ 'Operation': 'DepositPerformed', 'Amount': '3.75', 'UtcDateTime': '05/15/2019 19:48:51.099' }" },
        new Event() { Data = @"{ 'Operation': 'AccountCreated', 'CustomerId': '56', 'Balance': '0', 'UtcDateTime': '05/01/2019 11:30:00.084' }" },
        new Event() { Data = @"{ 'Operation': 'OwnerChanged', 'CustomerId': '7993', 'UtcDateTime': '05/25/2019 10:00:00.084' }" },
        new Event() { Data = @"{ 'Operation': 'DepositPerformed', 'Amount': '33.6', 'UtcDateTime': '05/20/2019 18:47:41.084' }" },
    };
```

When I transfer them to Redis, I create a LIST with the name that holds ID of the entity - *BankAccount_1*:

```
foreach (var item in DomainEvents)
{
    db.ListLeftPush(listName, item.Data); // listName = "BankAccount_1"
}
```

**Is this a good approach?**

My main concern is that I may end up with too many lists.

In this case we have a list per Account record.

So, if there's a million of Account records in my SQL Server DB - Redis will have as many lists.

To me it seems like it's the best we can do **in terms of performance**. The data is perfectly separated. E.g. when we need to fetch events for Bank Account with ID 665 - the query is simple and straightforward:

```
var events = db.ListRange("BankAccount_665", 0, -1);
```

IMHO, if we keep all the events in one List / HashSet - it's going to be impossible to FILTER them properly. Because the data is in JSON format. We'll have to fetch extremely huge amount of data which needs filtering. It's a depletion of CPU resources & RAM.

What are your thoughts?

**Also, do you think it'd be beneficial to back up events in SQL Server?**

I think of the following schema:

| **ID** | **AggregateType** | **AggregateID** | **JsonData** |

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think it's not the best idea to keep valuable information inside an in-memory database. I would be more comfortable with a DB which eventually would persist data to the disk. SQL DB IMO would be more preferable as it believed to be more suitable for analytic queries.